# Get a page excerpt with the Django CMS

Tags: django, django-cms

I want to show an excerpt of the about-page in the footer of every subpage of our Django-CMS installation.

What is the best way to achieve this? I couldn't find a ready solution on Google, or here.

I know excerpts are easy with Django blogs, like zinnia or cmsplugin-blog; But I'd perfer not to turn the about-page into a blog entry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote this Template Tag that displays a certain `CMSPlugin` from the desired page.

```
from cms.models.pagemodel import Page

@register.simple_tag
def page_excerpt(page_id, slot=None, position=0):
    page = Page.objects.get(reverse_id=page_id, publisher_is_draft=False)
    if slot is None:
        placeholder = page.placeholders.all()[0] # by default, take the first one.
    else:
        placeholder = page.placeholders.filter(slot=slot)[0]
    cmsplugin = placeholder.cmsplugin_set.order_by('position')[position]
    return cmsplugin.render_plugin()
```

The Template Tag takes the page-id, the name of the placeholder, and the position of the `CMSPlugin` as arguments. So I can have a special placeholder for the excerpt in the template and/or simply use the first or second.. `CMSPlugin` of an existing placeholder.

Possible improvements:

- better error handling
- more flexible generation of the excerpt